# Oplon LBL ADC - Browser reporting NS_ERROR_NET_INADEQUATE_SECURITY with HTTP2

Tags: http2

Today by connecting to our site through the browser we have reported this problem `NS_ERROR_NET_INADEQUATE_SECURITY` 
anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem, you can set TLS protocols and Ciphersuites to obtain Perfect Forward Security (PFS) and your site

You can set them for all ADC listeners or for a specific listener and your site will work again.

Protocols:

```
TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
```

cipherSuites:

```
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

After setting try with all updated browsers and check with www.ssllabs.com your PFS security score. I suggest you to check at regular intervals of time your score to be able to adjust the security of your site.

[image: ADC Settings-ADCs-Edit ADC config- SSL Parameters]